# Spring no mapping found for HTTP request with URI[require.js] in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring

Ok the full error is `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sequenziatore/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/js/libs/require.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'`
When i start the web app on a tomcat7 server, it open on the right page index.jsp, but it doesn't load the script require.js...I looked around for the other post and i find to add ${pageContext.request.contextPath} when requesting the require.js and also adding  to the spring-servlet.xml
but it gives me this error, i also moved all the css and js in a folder called resources but nothing...Without the ${pageContext.request.contextPath} it gives me the same error..

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
 <web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And the spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.presenter"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

And the index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/screen.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script data-main="js/main" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home"></div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the  ${pageContext.request.contextPath} and data-main="js/main" will become resources/js/main

Comment: a simple solution to a seemingly complex problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Maven dependency support for JSP in pom.xml file and remove web.xml file.

```
<!-- Add support for JSP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or,
simply remove this `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

Now, the issue will get resolved.